# Map stored procedure's result to C# object (variable number of columns)

Tags: c#, dynamic, ado.net

I have a stored procedure in my database, which returns a variable number of columns. Is there a C# object where I can map the result of this procedure?

Comment: A Dictionary maybe? Or even a List<Dictionary>> if you return multiple rows.

Comment: IEnumerable<dynamic>

Comment: or DataTable...

Comment: You can write your own object if you like.  None of us are going to know any better how you intend to use the data.

Comment: A dataset is a C# object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use from loosely typed container types: like `object`, `Dictionary`, `DataRow`... or use dynamic objects or either extend `DynamicObject` yourself:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx